# Use logrotate with manual file management

Tags: logrotate

I'm trying to use logrotate with some unfriendly software.  I don't want to court data loss with the *copytruncate* option.  Instead, the software has an internal (gimped) rotate capability.  Unfortunately, all it can do is add a numeric suffix.

What I'm looking for is a way to inform logrotate that it can manage the aging of logfiles, but that through *firstaction* or *prerotate*, I'll actually manage the backup of the current log to a numeric suffixed file.

I suppose I could do this all manually, but my hope is that by using logrotate it's more easily understood by whoever comes after me.

Answer (score 0):

You can script all kinds of things with logrotate.  You can even write an external script to stop the service, let log rotate rotate the log, and then have another script restart it.  This is essentially what happens with apache logs managed by log rotate.

Why in the world would anyone want to manage logs on a *nix box with anything OTHER than log rotate? It's a perfectly good wheel and it always puzzles me when people want to keep re-inventing it.

Comment: I don't disagree that logrotate is the way to go.  What I'm trying to do is use it as much as I can while still dealing with the limitations of the legacy product whose logs I'm trying to manage.